# How to change corner radius of a context menu preview?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, contextmenu, rounded-corners

I am using a UIViewController as a preview view for the context menu for my table cells. I don't see a way to change the corner radius of the standard blurred background that appears behind my view. Changing the corner radius of the view controller that is used for the preview does not affect the blurred background behind, and leaves these annoying edges in each corner:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code please?